# Is there a way to present row data as columns in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, subquery, reformat

I'm pulling the following data out of a couple of tables where I'm interested in the status of a couple of RowID's:

```
SELECT  T.DateTime, T2.Node, T2.ID, T.RowID,
CASE 
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusA%' THEN '1'
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusB%' THEN '2'
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusC%' THEN '3'
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusD%' THEN '4'
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusE%' THEN '5'
    WHEN T.Status like 'StatusF' THEN '6'
    ELSE '0'
END AS ActualStatus

FROM Table1 T INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T.ID
WHERE (T.RowID = '1' or T.RowId = '2')
```

and the output looks like

| DateTime | Node | ID | RowID | ActualStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/06/2022 10:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 10:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 11:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 11:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 2 |
| 28/06/2022 12:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 12:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 13:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 3 |
| 28/06/2022 13:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 14:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 14:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |

I want it to look like:

| DateTime | Node | ID | Row1Status | Row2Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/06/2022 10:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 11:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 2 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 12:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 13:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 3 |
| 28/06/2022 14:00 | 5201 | 4160cddd-ba27-44b1-b2f1-13c5c8ac379e | 1 | 1 |

But I can't work out how to make that happen. I've tried sub-queries and pivots but nothing works.

Comment: Can you share your input table and the DBMS you're using?

Comment: Have you tried one of your tags, `pivot`?